# Subscript right below the variable

Tags: math-mode, equations

`$x_{max}(n)$` does not look good, because `max` takes to much space horizontally, and `n` goes too far. What is a good way to write such thing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Not sure if there's a good way with that nomenclature. The subscript baseline is lower than the main text baseline, but not so low that the main text and subscript text won't overlap. Would something like `\max (x(n))` work instead?

Comment: I don't really see any alternative; having "max" below the *x* is not only typographically bad, but also against any mathematical convention.

Comment: I think `$x_{\max}(n)$` looks just fine. Of course you could make up some new notation for that, like `$\bar{x}(n)$`.

Comment: @mafp, don't abuse `\max` that way, better write `$x_{\text{max}}(n)$`, that works in all cases of text subscripts

Comment: I'm not really using max. It was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in \! for negative space (fixed amount) or else use a \rule with a negative horizontal argument, as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\parindent 0in 
\begin{document}
$x_{\!max}\!(n)$  versus\\
$x_{\rule{-.2ex}{0ex}max}\rule{-.1ex}{0ex}(n)$  versus\\
$x_{max}(n)$
\end{document}
```